# Laravel 4: Custom Validation Rule

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I've an `owners` table with a `user_id` field, this field can be `NULL`. because not every owner may have an user account. I need to check if the `user_id` field is `NUL`L on the `owners` table, before creating a user and updating that table. How do I do it with Laravel's Validation ?

Answer (score 1):

You can extend the validator, as per the docs

```
Validator::extend('foo', function($attribute, $value, $parameters)
{
    return $value == NULL;
});
```

See the custom validation section
http://four.laravel.com/docs/validation